# how can i customize that suitable to IE?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, customization

I've tried with all I can to customize to look good in IE, especially IE6 and IE7 but does not work, I looking for help/ponters, especially on part of spray category and menu bar.
thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Sorry, website times out for me.

Comment: Yeah, it seems very flakey. I just got on, but sometimes there were database errors and now it seems to gone for good.

Comment: Please describe the actual problem you have, and preferably provide some sample code, rather than expecting us to visit a random site. You haven't really explained the problem well enough to get much useful help here. Oh, and yikes, just give up on IE6 already. Are you really still getting significant traffic from IE6 users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you are asking, but I'm guessing you have problems that your site isn't displayed correctly in IE.

Your first steps to correct this are:

A) Remove the XML prolog (`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`) from the beginning of you source code, because this puts IE6 in [quirks mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode).

B) Validate your page. It has several HTML errors: http://validator.w3.org/check?verbose=1&uri=http%3A%2F%2Fscreenshield.co.nz%2F

Comment: +1 for being about as helpful as is possible given the question. Getting out of Quirks Mode is the single biggest thing that will solve a vast number of IE6 issues. And making sure your HTML is valid will solve a lot of the rest. Beyond that, you'll need to ask a more specific question.